Reverse Proxy Setup on Synology Router WRX560
I want to setup a reverse proxy on my Synology WRX560, although upon looking for how to set this up, I've only come across a thread on Synology Official Forum; https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/2/post/119900?page=5&sort=oldest with numerous people requesting this for SRM.
And within that link, there is a package on git; although it seems to not have much positive feedback on getting it setup on various routers. Therefore I'm hoping someone is able to help, not so with the package on git; but how to get this working on my router.
